# Does a Mini-DVI to DVI cable exist that's more than 6 inches long?

Tags: video, macbook-pro, display, video-adapter

I have a plastic MacBook that I like to use both on the go and at home, where I have a monitor, keyboard/mouse, speakers, etc that I hook up to use it more or less as a desktop. This works great, for the most part, except for the adaptor - it's constantly getting snagged on my desk due to the sheer size of the DVI-DVI connection.

I've tried looking online for a 3 foot Mini-DVI to DVI cable so that I can eliminate this bulk, but without success. It seems that both Apple and a number of third parties are more than willing to sell adaptors for the Mini-DVI, but none sell actual cables.

Have I missed something in my search? Or do manufacturers simply not produce the product I describe? If the latter, is it due to restrictions on using the Mini-DVI connector, a technical problem that requires the adaptor to be no longer than 6 or so inches, or perceived lack of demand?

Comment: +1. I hate those fat adapter dongles hanging off the MacBook. I can live with an adapter, but it should be hidden away behind the back of the monitor.

Answer (score 3):

I think the idea would be to use the [Mini-DVI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DVI) to [DVI adapter](http://store.apple.com/us/product/M9321G/B) at one end of a DVI to DVI cable.
The specs should be checked for maximum workable length ([example](http://www.scala.com/support/technical-faqs/hardware-faq-hardware-stability-guide/dvi-vga-cable.html))

Comment: That's my current setup, but I hate the bulk at the end of the cable. I would much rather have a Mini-DVI to DVI cable with the adapter on the monitor end to convert to DVI, if such a cable exists.

Answer (score 0):

[Monoprice](http://www.monoprice.com) is usually the best bet for cables and they don't see to have anything.  May just not be popular enough yet.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a 3 ft one on Amazon: [http://www.amazon.com/Monoprice-32AWG-Mini-DisplayPort-Cable/dp/B0034X9380](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0034X9380)

Although, I couldn't find it on the Monoprice website.

Comment: That's a mini-*Displayport* to DVI, not mini-*DVI* to DVI.